# Перебор элементов и помещение в таблицу

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Мне надо перебрать все элементы и воткнуть их в таблицу. Я вроде их перебираю, но в таблицу выходит только последнее значение, при чем оно дублируется 10 раз. Как мне сделать так, чтоб выводили 10 нужных мне заголовков?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    for (SMXMLElement *elem in package)
    {
        SMXMLElement* str = [elem attributeNamed:@"key"];
            cell.textLabel.text = str;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

P.S. вот так я подправил для понимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Делегирует из вьевера и узнает сколько строчек в секции для Табличного представления.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Табличное представление запрашивает информацию и вьювер для отрисорвки ячейки.
Таким образом здесь нужно нарисовать ячейку и вернуть ее как результирующее из метода.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       SMXMLElement  *elem=[package objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *str = [elem attributeNamed:@"key"];
       cell.textLabel.text =  str;
       return cell;
    }
```

пишу в слепую так, что разбирайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, так все заработала. Мой цыкл похоже был лишний!

Comment: Угу, numberOfRowsInSection собственно и говорит табличному вьюверу сколько элементов. А потом он уже отрисовывает те элементы, которые нужно показать на экран через cellForRowAtIndexPath. Это очень важный момент, так как при смене количествва элементов, вьювер должен быть в курсе, иначе можно отхватить... эксепшен.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разьяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю это делается в методе `cellForRowAtIndexPath: index`

Тогда надо брать номер элемента, `index` тобишь, в этом Вашем `package` и присваивать `cell`.

Сейчас в Вашем варианте все цикл проходит, запоминает последнее значение и присваивает `cell'у`.

Comment: точнее в цикле для каждой ячейки последовательно присваиваются все значения, а по выходу остается последнее

Comment: Если я вас правилно понял, то сделать мне нужно вот таким образом ???

 cell.textLabel.text = [str objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];